# Is it possible to use the "native" window.plugins.pushNotification from cordova in Monaca?

Tags: monaca

Has anyone been able to get push notifications working in their Monaca app, by not using Monaca's backend service? For what it's worth, I also tried using their backend service, but couldn't get it to work and even if it did, it's not nearly good enough according to their documentation.

I'm trying to use PushWoosh.

Below returns "undefined" .

```js
alert(window.plugins.pushNotification);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as importing the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) as a custom plugin, which requires the upgraded plan. They just don't offer it as a "core" plugin.